# OS-X: How to copy files according to their file types from an external hard drive onto an OS-X computer?

Tags: macos, automator, copy-paste, file

I have a lot of files (music, pictures, documents) on an external hard drive that I want to copy into the respective folders on OS-X. I would like to automate the copying process and put all .bmp, .jpg and .jpeg into the pictures folder on OS-X, .mp3 into music and so on for all the different file types.

How can I automate this and what software could I use?

Comment: How are the files organized on the drive? Why is just selecting them in Finder and moving them to the target folders not an option?

Comment: They are in various different folders, on a 600GB harddrive. It's a badly maintained backup harddrive, with no apparent organization whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to run the following script in Terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

find /Volumes/NAME_OF_EXTERNAL_DRIVE -type f -print | while read f; do
    case "$f" in
       *.jpg) cp "$f" "~/Pictures/${f##.*/}"
              ;;
       *.mp3) cp "$f" "~/Music/${f##.*/}"
              ;;
       *) echo "Don't know how to handle '$f'"
          ;;
     esac
done
```

Add lines for additional suffixes and target folders as needed (and also keep in mind that `.jpg` is not the same as `.JPG`).

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an app that can do this sort of operation? I'd have to get into AppleScript.

Comment: That's shell scripting actually. Let's see if whether others have ideas as well.

Comment: It's Unix and not AppleScript? I'll have a look at it then.

Comment: Also note JPEG and jpeg . is also a valid extension that may be used by a file